# Running the trigger only when the binding is equal to a certain value

Tags: wpf, binding, visibility, datatrigger

I want to run a `trigger` that makes visibilty to **Visible** only when the `binding` is a certain value, in another case so visibilty is **Hidden**.

Here my grid:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyProp}" Value="10">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
     </Grid>
```

How do I do that in any other case, the visibility will be **Hidden**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the default value as hidden then in your style. By `default value` will always be `hidden` and will turn to visible only in case value is 10 -

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyProp}" Value="10">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
 </Grid>
```